# How to solve this recurrence relation? $a_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i a_{n-i}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to find the number of ways to product $n$ terms of a monoid in specific order.

Let $G$ be a monoid, and $x_i$'s are elements of $G$.

We see that

$x_1$

$x_1 x_2$

$(x_1 x_2) x_3, ~~~ x_1 (x_2 x_3)$

$((x_1 x_2) x_3)x_4, ~~~ (x_1(x_2x_3))x_4, ~~~ (x_1x_2)(x_3x_4), ~~~
x_1((x_2x_3)x_4), ~~~ x_1(x_2(x_3x_4))$

$\ldots$

In this way,
let $a_n$ be a number of a way to product $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ with order-preserving.

Then $a_1 =1$, $a_2 = 1$, $a_3 = 2$.

And we find that $a_4 = a_1 a_3 + a_2 a_2 + a_3 a_1$.

Similarly, the general term $a_n$ is recursively obtained by

$$a_n = a_1 a_{n-1} + a_2 a_{n-2} + \ldots + a_{n-2} a_2 + a_{n-1} a_1
= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i a_{n-i}.$$

The initial value is $a_1 =1$ and $a_2 = 2$.

How to find the general term explicitly?

Comment: Generating functions should come in handy here

Comment: Hint: define $c_n:=a_{n+1}$ for $n\ge0$ so $c_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}c_jc_{n-j}$. Now [take your pick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Proof_of_the_formula) of proofs that $c_n:=\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}$, so $a_n=\frac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}$. The first of the six proofs at that link follows @SarveshRavichandranIyer's advice.